# WPF Codeplex Dashboarding BidirectionalDial

Tags: c#, wpf, dashboard, codeplex, gauge

```
BidirectionalDial tempGauge = new Dial360();

if (chp.DialType.Equals("360")) 
{
    tempGauge = new Dial360();
}
else if (chp.DialType.Equals("180"))
{
    tempGauge = new Dial180North();
}
else if (chp.DialType.Equals("90"))
{
    tempGauge = new Dial90SouthEast();
}

tempGauge.FontSize = GaugeDialProperty.getGaugeFontSize(chp.DialType, chp.MaxVal);
```

`GetGaugeFontSize` returns an integer but it is only applied to `Dial360`. It is not applyed to `Dial180North` and `Dial90SouthEast` and they use default font size. How can I solve this issue?

Solution:

```
            Grid dg = (Grid)tempGauge.Content;
            foreach (UIElement ui in dg.Children)
            {
                Type elementType = ui.GetType();
                if (elementType.FullName == "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock")
                {
                    TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)ui;
                    tb.FontSize = fontSize;
                }
            }
```